# Adding Alias in joinWith(YII2) in Linux is not working

Tags: php, mysql, linux, yii2

I'm working in this query.

```
$data = RtvReqDet::find()
            ->joinWith(['header', 'rtvCard.serial sn', 'rtvCard.serial.item si', 'rtvCard.item ri' ])
            ->select([
                'header.requested_by as classification',
                'ifnull(sn.no, rtvCard.serial_no) AS serial',
                'ifnull(si.no, ri.no) AS item',
                'ifnull(si.uom, ri.uom) AS uom',
                'COUNT(ifnull(sn.no, rtvCard.serial_no)) AS qty',
            ])
            ->where(['rtv_spare_parts_requisition_id' => $record->id ])
            ->groupBy(['serial'])->all();
```

It's working on Windows. But is not working on Linux and giving this error:

```
Exception 'yii\base\InvalidParamException' with message 'app\models\RtvCard has no relation named "serial AS sn".'
```

I tried lowering my php version and mysql version exactly with the Linux. but I can still transact on my windows. So it doesn't have any conflict with php and mysql version. what do you think is wrong with this?

this is the rtvCard model. This was customized by my colleague whom I've worked with before. I deleted some relations where I think not needed in this discussion.

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use app\components\ActiveRecord;
use app\components\FieldException;
use yii\base\Exception;

class RtvCard extends ActiveRecord  {

    static function tableName() {
        return "rtv_card";
    }

    static function objectName()    {
        return "rtv card";
    }

    // RELATIONS
    function getCustomer()  {
        return $this->hasOne(Customer::className(), [ "id" => "customer_id" ])->from([ "customer" => Customer::tableName() ]);
    }
    function getSerial()    {
        return $this->hasOne(SerialNumbers::className(), [ "id" => "serial_id" ])->from([ "serial" => SerialNumbers::tableName() ]);
    }
    function getItem()  {
        return $this->hasOne(Items::className(), [ "id" => "item_id" ])->from([ "item" => Items::tableName() ]);
    }
    function getTransfer()  {
        return $this->hasOne(RtvTransferDetail::className(), [ "rtv_card_id" => "id" ])->from([ "transfer" => RtvTransferDetail::tableName() ]);
    }

    // USED FOR ERROR MESSAGES
    static $attributeLabels = [
        "id" => "ID",
        "no" => "RTV No",
        "item_id" => "Item",
        "serial_id" => "Serial no.",
        "defect_id" => "Defect",
        "description" => "Complaints",
        "date_received" => "Date received",
        "received_by" => "Received by",
        "customer_id" => "Dealer",
        "reference_no" => "Reference no.",
        "tag" => "Tag",
        "technician_id" => "Technician",
        "warehouse" => "Warehouse",
    ];
    // FIELD NAMES IN VIEW IF NOT THE SAME WITH ATTRIBUTE
    // USE STATIC::GET-FIELD($ATTRIBUTE-NAME)
    // ATTRIBUTE NAME SHOULD BE THE TABLE ATTRIBUTES ITSELF ( NOT THE FIELD NAME IN VIEWS )
    // ATTRIBUTE NAME => FIELD NAME
    static $attributeFields = [
        "item_id" => "item",
        "serial_id" => "serial",
        "defect_id" => "defect",
        "customer_id" => "dealer",
        "received_by" => "received-by",
        "date_received" => "received-date",
        "reference_no" => "reference-no",
        "open_serial_id_no" => "no",
        "open_serial_id_item" => "item",
        "technician_id" => "technician",
    ];
```

Comment: Update you question and add  your rtvCard Model ..please   in your question you have  ." not work in Linux"   but work on others OS ?

Comment: Which Yii 2 version is this?

Comment: @scaisEdge yes! not working on Linux OS but working on Windows. 
uhm, it's like this on RtvCardModel, I have 2 scenario, which,
1.) if user choose serial tbl lookup, it has a default item tbl related, 
2. if user choose to input serial, he needs to choose item tbl. so, that's why I have that kind of joinwith

Comment: @BlackSkull   then update your question and add  your rtvCard Model .. code ..(namespace   incuded)  and tell us the version of yii2 you are using

Comment: @scaisEdge on my windows, I'm using 2.0.7 while on the Linux, 2.0.6 
do I need to update the version currently using on Linux?

Comment: I have posted some suggestion hope are useful

Answer (score 1):

Since Yii 2.0.7, the shortcut for relational aliases is `'rtvCard.serial sn'` <strike>and not `'rtvCard.serial AS sn'`</strike> (From [Bizley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3364821/bizley)'s comment `AS` works too)

From the [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relation-table-aliases):

> If you need an alias for an intermediate table when joining over nested relations, e.g. `$query->joinWith(['orders.product'])`, you need to nest the `joinWith` calls like in the following example:
>
> ```
> $query->joinWith(['orders o' => function($q) {
>     $q->joinWith('product p');
> }])
> ->where('o.amount > 100');
> ```

So in your case:

```
RtvReqDet::find()
    ->joinWith(['rtvCard' => function($q) {
        $q->joinWith(['serial sn', 'serial.item si', 'item ri']);
    }])
    ->select([ ...
```

Comment: by the way, I already did this. that was the first one I tried too. And it's running smoothly on "Windows" I forgot to mention this. sorry.

Comment: What versions of Yii and MySQL are you using?

Comment: @topher thank you for sharing this! I will definitely try this later.

Answer (score 1):

Is better that your version are the same on both installation ... but check fo sure that your file si properly UpperCase  ..

```
RtvCard.php
```

.. because windows  filenames are case insensitive  but linux are case Sensitive.
Check also in you controller that the use classname..... refer  to the proper case sensitive name

Comment: ohh. I did use camel case. I only forgot to uppercase RtvCard here. haha

Comment: I will try to update my copy of Yii on the linux OS. I think, the only problem why the two OS version were mismatch is because, I think we didn't upload the vendors folder. or so I thought? but I will upload all files once we finished our system. thanks!